# How do I remove a partition from elements external hard-drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-drive, partitioning, backtrack

The hard drive was partitioned to have a ubuntu ISO boot as we didn't have a 2GB USB at the time to just put ubuntu on (What a fail I know -.-'). This partition was made with backtrack 5 KDE R3 (Assuming this is why I can't find a way to get rid of it whatsoever on windows). I can see it on windows, along with another partition I want to remove (200GB linux-access-only hidden storage) both are empty, but the main hard-drive isn't and there's over 100+ GB of stuff on the main hard-drive and I don't want to remove all of it (Waiting time issue to unload and reload files, ain't nobody got no time for dat) just to re-format the entire external drive all-together. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open disks from dash, delete the partition that's already on the drive by pressing the - sign, Only **if no longer needed**.

[image]

Create a new EXT4 partition, by clicking the + sign,  and format the drive.

[image]

Once the partition is created, click on the little wheels to format the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove the partition from within Windows, it is very possible and simple to do.
Open Disk Management, you can find it by right click on start on Windows 8/10, or from control panel in 7.

From here you will see a graphical display of all disks connected to the system. Find the external drive, it's usually disk 1, since computers start counting at 0. You'll see there are a few partitions. Delete the "unknown" ones by right click -> delete. There will be a warning about the partitions possibly containing data for another OS; proceed. You can then extend any Windows-readable partition to span the whole drive by right click -> extend. If there are none, simply right click the free space and create one.